# How do I install drivers for a wifi antenna onto my Pi?

Tags: driver, pi-1

I have been following [this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-a-wifi-network-that-only-transmits-cat-pictures-with-a-raspberry-pi/) and am at the point of entering the following:

`sudo /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

This *should* setup the wifi network however my Pi returns the following:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

From this I've deduced that the drivers were at fault, so I found the MiniDVD that came with it and put these on my computer-the Linux drivers are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ele33y4kcwvn1ub/AADJQDA4BjjmOKhU208Tk1Cna?dl=0).  I have also set up FileZilla to SFTP to the Pi.  What should I do to install the drivers?

The Pi is a 1B and the software is the most up-to-date Raspbian, as done by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.  No desktop; I've been using SSH.

Answer (score 1):

It us **EXTREMELY** unlikely that there will be drivers for the ARM6 processor on the Pi!

All the drivers you need for most WiFi devices are already built into the kernel.

Not all WiFi devices/drivers support AdHoc modes.

I suggest you get the WiFi working as normal FIRST, then try your project.